# Is there a keyboard shortcut to increase the screen in XFCE

Tags: centos, xfce

I am using `CentOS 7` with the `XFCE` environment.  Is there a quick option/keyboard shortcut to increase the screen size?

Comment: What do you mean with "screen size"? For sure not how to get a 27" monitor from a 24" monitor

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I mean have some code which launches jsp application and its font is too small that I am unable to read. So is there any functionality to zoom in the screen or the font of the jsp application. Thanks

Comment: Edit question to explain. Also tell us what jsp is. And be clearer: You say that you want code to launch the jsp application (is this what you want?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default XFCE with **compositing turned on** has a zoom feature which can be enabled by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and mouse scrolling Up or Down.

In Window Manager Tweaks this key <kbd>Alt</kbd> might be changed to <kbd>Super</kbd> (A windows key, ⊞).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is a kind of uick and easy solution I was looking for. P.S. sorry got some issues so was unable to login to the site for a while. Upvoted and accepted as an answer.